# How can grep interpret literally a string that contains an asterisk and is fed to grep through a variable?

Tags: bash, grep

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
CLASSPATH="/blah/libs/*:/blah/more/libs"
CMD="java -cp $CLASSPATH MainClass"
ALREADY_RUNNING_PID=`ps -ef --no-headers | grep $CMD | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
if [ "$ALREADY_RUNNING_PID" ]; then
      echo "Already running"
      exit 1
fi
$CMD &
```

problem is it doesnt work due to the asterisk in the CMD variable. how can i tell grep to see the variable value as it is? Any solution? It is mandatory that grep is fed through the variable.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are not using regular expressions you can use `fgrep $CMD` instead of `grep`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not grep, it's

```
CLASSPATH="/blah/libs/*:/blah/more/libs"
```

If you do

```
echo $CLASSPATH
```

you should see that your shell has expanded the * to all files in that directory.  To remedy this, just use single quotes to prevent globbing:

```
CLASSPATH='/blah/libs/*:/blah/more/libs'
```

Comment: I thought that too, but I added that echo statement before the CMD=... assignement and it is not expanded... i dont know why. 
Anyway I cant do single quoting because actually CLASSPATH in my real world example consists of other vars:
CLASSPATH="$BASEPATH/libs/*:$BASEPATH/morelibs/*"

Comment: Although maybe i could concatenate, but it seems too ugly to be the only solution

Answer (score 1):

Totally unrelated to your specific grep problem, but [jps](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jps.html) will report on running Java processes and possibly make your grepping easier since you'd most likely have to just do:

```
jps | grep MainClass
```

(or something similar)