# grep match exact substring ignoring regex syntax

Tags: bash, grep

Is there some way to make grep match an *exact*  string, and not parse it as a regex? Or is there some tool to escape a string properly for grep?

```
$ version=10.4
$ echo "10.4" | grep $version
10.4
$ echo "1034" | grep $version # shouldn't match
1034
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use grep -F or fgrep.

```
$ echo "1034" | grep -F $version # shouldn't match
$ echo "10.4" | grep -F $version
10.4
```

See man page:

> ```
>    -F, --fixed-strings
>          Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated
>          by newlines, any of which is to be matched.
> ```

I was looking for the term "literal match" or "fixed string".

<sub>(See also [Using grep with a complex string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217454/using-grep-with-a-complex-string) and [How can grep interpret literally a string that contains an asterisk and is fed to grep through a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537104/how-can-grep-interpret-literally-a-string-that-contains-an-asterisk-and-is-fed-to))</sub>